# How to fix or bypass the DHCP handshake to get an IP address

Tags: networking, dhcp

My linux box can't seem to get a DHCPOFFER from my router. This is blocking me from getting internet access on the linux box.

**Here's the setup:**
I have two computers, a linux box called mocha and a windows box called latte. I'm trying to use latte get more information about what's wrong with mocha. I have a Netgear WNR2000 v3 router.

**Mocha**

- had fully functional internet access until a recent reboot
- (thinks it) is broadcasting DISCOVER messages every 15 seconds or so
- gets `no answer` to `dhcping -v`
- is running `dhcpdump`, which is dumping

  - the REQUEST, ACK, and INFORM messages broadcast between the router and latte
  - DISCOVER messages broadcast by itself (mocha)

**Latte**

- is connected by ethernet to the same router as Mocha and has fully functional internet access
- is running wireshark, filtered for "bootp"

  - I expect it should see all DHCP messages that are broadcast on the network, including the DISCOVER messages (supposedly) broadcast by mocha
  - It is actually seeing only the REQUEST, ACK, and INFORM messages being broadcast and unicast between itself and the router.

In conclusion, I think mocha isn't getting an OFFER message because its DISCOVER messages aren't getting through. What can I do to make them get through? Or is there a way I can skip DHCP discovery and fabricate a working IP address for it in order to get internet access?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'fabricate a working IP address' you mean assign a static IP then sure.  Just edit your interface config file at /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts and change it from dhcp to none.  For example:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
NOZEROCONF=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
DNS1=X.X.X.X  <= dns server
DNS2=X.X.X.X  <= dns server
DEFROUTE=yes
NAME=eth0
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=X.X.X.X  <= your assigned IP
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=X.X.X.X <= the default gateway
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

then just execute command:

```
service network restart
```